# Problema con While en async/await

Tags: javascript, while, async-await

Tengo una duda con respecto a la utilización de While en llamadas asíncronas. Yo estoy llamando a una API que tiene como parámetro "page" que representa la página en la que está la data que quiero traer. Para traer toda la data, lo que quiero hacer es recorrer todas las páginas disponibles, por lo que me dispongo a hacer un while hasta que el JSON devuelto esté vacío.No se porque me está fallando al entrar en el loop. Me lo trae undefined.

```
     async getAllData(){
      let i=1
      let URL=web+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page="+i
      let result=await Axios.get(URL)
      this.data[i]=result.data
      while(result.data.length>0){        
        i++;
        result=await Axios.get(URL)
        this.data[i]=result.data
      }
```

Comment: por favor, si la respuesta te ha ayudado márcala como aceptada para que la pregunta quede *cerrada* y más usuarios con el mismo problema sepan que esa solución es válida!

Answer (score 1):

Parece que falta **evaluar el resultado de la promesa**, para cuando no hay mas páginas.

Primero, hay que pasar la `URL` con la página dinámica dentro del ciclo while:

```
while(result.data.length>0){        
    i++;
    URL = web+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page="+i;
    result=await Axios.get(URL);
    ...
}
```

Luego, hay que evaluar el resultado de la promesa dentro del ciclo while:

```
async getAllData(){
     let i=1;
     let URL=web+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page="+i;
     let result=await Axios.get(URL);
     this.data[i]=result.data;
     while(result.data.length>0){        
        i++;
        result=await Axios.get(URL);
        if(result.data !== undefined){        
            this.data[i]=result.data;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Por último, no se como se esta llamando la función `getAllData`, pero como hay una referencia a `data`, la sugerencia es llamarla con el método `apply`:

```
getAllData.apply(this);
```

Se puede mejorar el patrón, pero esta solución debe funcionar.

**Modificación dinámica de cadenas (String)**

> porque hay que volver a definir URL dentro del while, cuando ya lo estaba fuera?

La propuesta fue crear una cadena dinámica, concatenando valores dentro de la variable `URL`:

```
let i = 1;
let URL = web+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page="+i;
//console.log(URL)
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
```

Esto funciono bien para el primer ciclo de iteración del while, pero no para los siguientes ciclos, pues el incremento de la variable `i`, no se esta reasignando a la misma; la cadena que hay en `URL` se formo dinámicamente fuera del `while`, **pero su resultado es estático**:

```
//suponiendo 4 iteraciones
while(result.data.length > 0){
    i++;
    console.log(URL);
//obtendrias la siguiente salida
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
}
```

Se tiene que reasignar el valor de `i` dentro del ciclo while, es decir la misma operación de concatenación que se propuso al inicio  de la función, pero esta vez reasignando el valor de `i` para cada iteración:

```
//suponiendo 4 iteraciones
while(result.data.length > 0){
    i++;
    console.log(web+"/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page="+i);
//obtendrias la siguiente salida
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=1
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=2
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=3
//web/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&page=4
}
```

Como se puede observar, se sigue pasando el valor de `web` de forma estática, igual para el otro pedazo de string "wp/..." pero el valor de `i` **se cambia dinamicamente**, para cada iteración del ciclo `while`, pues se modifica el valor inicial de `i` (la cual ya esta definida en la función principal) con `i++`, dentro del scope del ciclo `while`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona. Pero sigo sin entender porque hay que volver a definir URL dentro del while, cuando ya lo estaba fuera. Si cambiara el tipo de variable a var valdría?

Comment: @Deveter Se actualizó la respuesta, espero que sea de ayuda, si consideras que la respuesta fue de ayuda no olvides aceptarla y votar, saludos.